# Javascript Date Eval Format

Tags: macros, javascript, format, timestamp

I have a javascript to return via eval the date of today in YYYY-MM-D format

The code javascript is

```
var d= new Date(); var m=((d.getMonth()+1)<10)?'0'+(d.getMonth()+1):(d.getMonth()+1); d.getFullYear()+"-"+m+"-"+d.getDate();
```

This return the date format YYYY-MM-D

I need to have the format DD-MM-YYYY

Example of date April, 7 2019

Actual: 2019-04-7 (US format)

Desidered: 07-04-2019 (UE format)

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD isn't US date format, it is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). US date format is MM-DD-YYYY, otherwise known as "the stupidest way to arrange a date format".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

> var d= new Date(); var
>   m=((d.getMonth()+1)<10)?'0'+(d.getMonth()+1):(d.getMonth()+1);var
>   day=d.getDate()<10?'0'+d.getDate():d.getDate()
>   ;day+"-"+m+"-"+d.getFullYear();

Answer (score 0):

I would create a small function for padding with 0s so the code for the formatted date is more readable.

```
function pad(val){ return ('0' + val).slice(-2); }
var current_datetime = new Date();
var formatted_date = pad(current_datetime.getDate()) + "-" + 
    pad(current_datetime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + current_datetime.getFullYear();
```

Comment: It seems you're using [a modified version of `pad` as found on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript/10073788#10073788). But for your hardcoded values and for the input you're expecting, your `pad` function could be as simple as `function pad(val){ return ('0' + val).slice(-2); }`

Comment: That sounds great! Thank you @Arjan. I'll edit my answer because what I wanted is to add readability and simplicity to the answer.